# How can I improve these nested if statements?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way that I can reduce/improve this. I feel like my nesting "if"        could be reduced. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
public requirementsMet: boolean = false;
public flag1: boolean = false;
public flag2: boolean = false;
public flag3: boolean = false;
      
public check() {
  if(this.myOrder.myIndicator || this.myOrder.myCode === '123') {
    this.requirementsMet = true;
    if(this.myOrder.myIndicator && this.myOrder.myCode === null) {
      this.flag1 = true;
    }
    if(this.myOrder.myIndicator && this.myOrder.myCode === '123') {
      this.flag2 = true;
    }
    if(this.myOrder.myIndicator && this.myOrder.myCode) {
      this.flag3 = true;
    }
  } else {
    this.requirementsMet = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need all of those flags?

Comment: It's not clear what your overall goal is here. Sometimes it's better to keep your values in a data object for comparison, but I can't say knowing so little.

Comment: I am using the flags in my template to show a specific row and then what different text depending on the flag

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public requirementsMet: boolean = false;
public flag1: boolean = false;
public flag2: boolean = false;
public flag3: boolean = false;
  
public check() {
  this.requirementsMet = this.myOrder.myIndicator || this.myOrder.myCode === '123';
  if(this.myOrder.myIndicator) {
    this.flag1 = this.myOrder.myCode === null;
    this.flag2 = this.myOrder.myCode === '123';
    this.flag3 = this.myOrder.myCode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `requirementsMet` only depends on this one condition, so we could extract that first (wrapping in Boolean since short-circuiting exists):

```
this.requirementsMet = Boolean(this.myOrder.myIndicator || this.myOrder.myCode === '123');
```

Similarly, for the 3 flags:

```
this.flag1 = Boolean(this.myOrder.myIndicator && this.myOrder.myCode === null);
this.flag2 = Boolean(this.myOrder.myIndicator && this.myOrder.myCode === '123');
this.flag3 = Boolean(this.myOrder.myIndicator && this.myOrder.myCode);
```

So there's really no need for if statements at all.

Answer (score 1):

### De-structuring

The other answers are already pretty concice, but you can prevent repeating the path to the variables by destructuring `myOrder` like this:

```js
check() {
  const { myIndicator, myCode } = this.myOrder;
  
  this.requirementsMet = myIndicator || myCode === '123';
  
  if (myIndicator) {
    this.flag1 = myCode === null;
    this.flag2 = myCode === '123';
    this.flag3 = Boolean(myCode);
  }
}
```

*Note that everything that isn't private, is public by default. So you can just leave out the keyword.*

The same goes for:

```js
flag1 = false;
```

*Here, the fact that it's a boolean is inferred.*

Or when a default value makes little sense, you can just initialize them without assignment:

```js
flag1: boolean;
```